# Sound card (Audionengine D1) not working on new MacBook Pro Retina

Tags: audio, usb, macbook-pro

My soundcard (USB DLC Audioengine D1) is not working on my new MacBook. My old MacBook Air from 2012 has no problem with it.

When plugged in the device, I get this weird error in the Console. Looks like there is a problem with detecting the USB device.

```
20/03/2014 9:05:54.000 pm kernel[0]: USBF:    861.628    The IOUSBFamily is having trouble enumerating a USB device that has been plugged in.  It will keep retrying.  (Port 1 of Hub at 0x14000000)
20/03/2014 9:05:55.000 pm kernel[0]: USBF:    862.461    The IOUSBFamily has successfully enumerated the device (Port 1 of Hub at 0x14000000).
20/03/2014 9:05:55.000 pm kernel[0]: USBF:    862.769    IOUSBCompositeDriver(IOUSBDevice)::ConfigureDevice GetFullConfigDescriptor(0) #2 returned NULL, trying ResetDevice and then trying again
20/03/2014 9:05:55.000 pm kernel[0]: USBF:    862.999    IOUSBCompositeDriver(IOUSBDevice)::ConfigureDevice GetFullConfigDescriptor(0) #3 returned NULL, giving up
20/03/2014 9:05:55.997 pm UserEventAgent[11]: assertion failed: 13C64: com.apple.telemetry + 16493 [FDCB4ECA-3C5D-394A-BAEF-F6555BEB4239]: 0xffffffffe00002be
20/03/2014 9:06:29.000 pm kernel[0]: USB (XHCI Root Hub USB 2.0 Simulation):Port 2 on bus 0xa connected or disconnected: portSC(0xe0206e1)
20/03/2014 9:06:29.000 pm kernel[0]: USBF:    896.400    The IOUSBFamily is having trouble enumerating a USB device that has been plugged in.  It will keep retrying.  (Port 2 of Hub at 0x14000000)
20/03/2014 9:06:32.000 pm kernel[0]: USBF:    899.496    The IOUSBFamily was not able to enumerate a device.
20/03/2014 9:06:33.000 pm kernel[0]: USBF:    900.353    The IOUSBFamily is having trouble enumerating a USB device that has been plugged in.  It will keep retrying.  (Port 2 of Hub at 0x14000000)
20/03/2014 9:06:43.000 pm kernel[0]: USBF:    910. 66    The IOUSBFamily was not able to enumerate a device.
20/03/2014 9:06:43.000 pm kernel[0]: USBF:    910.922    The IOUSBFamily is having trouble enumerating a USB device that has been plugged in.  It will keep retrying.  (Port 2 of Hub at 0x14000000)
20/03/2014 9:06:44.000 pm kernel[0]: USBF:    911.779    The IOUSBFamily gave up enumerating a USB device after 10 retries.  (Port 2 of Hub at 0x14000000)
20/03/2014 9:06:44.000 pm kernel[0]: USBF:    911.779    The IOUSBFamily was not able to enumerate a device.
```

[image]

As recommended for similar problems, I have already tried resetting my NVRAM/PRAM - http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1379 - but that hasn't changed anything.

Comment: Is there a different version of OSX on the two computers? Also, just to eliminate the USB port, try plugging it into the other port if you have one.

Comment: Both running os x 10.9.2. And yes i have tried both ports with different cables.

Comment: Since they are on the same version I'd look to make sure there isn't some driver software you installed on the one that's working. It doesn't look like the product page has something, but who knows.

Comment: The sound card does not need a driver. There isn't even one for it. Apps installed on both machines is almost identical...

Comment: I'm out of ideas. You might want to try copying and pasting the text from the console which will help people having a similar problem if we can solve it here.

Comment: Yeah I added the console output to the question. Will keep you updated if I find out anything new. Thanks @dwightk

Comment: If you have a thunderbolt cable, or a bootable backup of the old macbook. Maybe try booting your new macbook from the old system, or vise-versa to check if it is an issue with the the software, or maybe the usb 3 port?

Comment: Good idea Kevin. Will try that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never got this working in the end, but instead I fixed it with a neat workaround. All MacBook Pros come with inbuilt optical out. Using a small adapter I could use that to digitally send the sound (just like USB) to the D1.